# How to run cronjob every 4 hours minus 1 second

Tags: cron, php, cpanel

I have data coming from API and I want to call it and dump the data in my db every 4 hours (current day data). I used the following :

```
0   */4 *   *   *
```

The data in my report is missing some values, I was thinking that the cronjob is called like this :

```
today       00:00:00  -> should return nothing for today results
today       04:00:00  -> should return data for today
              ....
today       20:00:00  -> should return data for today
tomorrow    24:00:00  -> should return data for today, but this is tomorrow !
```

So I am thinking now of calling it like this :

```
today       00:00:00  -> should return nothing for today results
today       03:59:59  -> should return data for today
              ....
today       19:59:59  -> should return data for today
tomorrow    23:59:59  -> should return data for today, but this is tomorrow !
```

I am not able to achieve this cronjob. Or there is a better way ?

Comment: Why a second? Why not a few minutes and avoid the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Seconds and negative time are not possible in crontab. Simply wait 59 seconds in the 59th minute of the previous hour. Example crontab:

```
#
# minute  0-59
# hour    0-23
# dom     1-31
# mon     1-12 (or names)
# dow     0-7  (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
#
59 23,3,7,11,15,19 * * * sleep 59 && /bin/datadump
```

Comment: This is what the asker asked for, but it isn't the right solution, because data that was generated between 23:59:59 and 0:00:00 will be missed.

Comment: @Gilles, exactly

Comment: Sure, but is this really a problem? Between 23:59:59 and 0:00:00 is only one second! Previous, the whole day was lost.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `cron` is designed to be more pattern recognition than arithmetic, so something like `-1 0 /4 * * *` won't work.
You can just specify each hour manually with the comma, so this should hopefully have the desired result:

```
59 59 3,7,11,15,19,23 * * *
```

Running a second before the hour is a little too trusting of your database, though. I'd personally give it a few more seconds' grace to wrap up (else it'll still dump tomorrow's data).